# Bounty Notices disappear on loading edits

Tags: bug, status-completed, live-refresh, post-notices

While browsing a question with a bounty, I started typing an answer. During that time, another answer was edited. On loading the edits for that answer, the bounty notice disappeared. I found this pretty confusing.  The notice appeared again only after I refreshed the page.

How about a fix?